# Clearing hidden input fields after postback

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I use hidden input fields to pass values form my javascript to the code behind. This works great but when I try to clear the fields from the code behind this doesn't work.

```
<input type="hidden" id="iRowNumberTblOne" name="iRowNumberTblOne" value="" runat="server"/>
```

I tired to do it by a few ways but they all don't work.

This is the easiest way and most logic but it doens't want to clear the values

```
iRowNumberTblOne.Value = "";
```

I even made a javascript, so the values would be cleared on the client side.
The alert comes up the first time "at startup" but after a postback it seems like the code behind doesn't find the javascript again.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function clearInputFileds() {
        alert('test');
            document.getElementById("ctl00_contentHolder_iSiteAlias").value = "";
            document.getElementById("ctl00_contentHolder_iServiceName").value = "";
            document.getElementById("ctl00_contentHolder_iRowNumberTblOne").value = "";
            document.getElementById("ctl00_contentHolder_iRowNumberTblTwo").value = "";

        }


    </script>
```

This is the code I use in the codebehind

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "", "clearInputFileds();", true);
```

Do you have any idea why these methods doesn't work? Maybe know a better way to clear this fields?

EDIT:

The input fields get filled by a javascript function. **This** function gets runs onClick.

```
function setClickedValues(siteAlias, serviceName, rowNumberTblOne, rowNumberTblTwo) {
            document.getElementById("ctl00_contentHolder_iSiteAlias").value = siteAlias;
            document.getElementById("ctl00_contentHolder_iServiceName").value = serviceName;
            document.getElementById("ctl00_contentHolder_iRowNumberTblOne").value = rowNumberTblOne;
            document.getElementById("ctl00_contentHolder_iRowNumberTblTwo").value = rowNumberTblTwo;

        }
```

Comment: What code assigns values to the hidden controls?

Comment: The easiest way does clear the value, but it might be replaced later. When and where is that code executed?

Comment: @Matthew Updated the post for you. at Guffa Both onLoad.

Comment: When is it you're calling `setClickedValues`?

Comment: When I click a button this button has this property:
ibtnTableTwo.OnClientClick = "setClickedValues('" + x + "', '" + xx + "', '"+ rowNumber + "', '" + j + "')";

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done in the code behind. But it is important to do it **at the right time in the ASP.Net Application Livecycle**. Take a closer look at:

- [ASP.NET Page Life Cycle Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)
- [Understanding ASP.NET View State](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx)

Usually you (re)set the value in the click event handlers of your submit button or in the LoadComplete event. If you do it before, the value will be **overwritten** at the time the ViewState is restored.

The following image is extremly usefull when working with ASP.Net pages and ViewState:

[image: ASP.NET Page Life Cycle]

*(Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)*

BTW: It is a very bad idea to reset the value in client code with hard coded ID's as they are subject to changes.

Comment: Omg thats the diagram I was looking for! Did it in the Page_PreRender and it works. Thanks alot!

Comment: @Freddy: That's why I have a copy of this sheet next to my keyboard :-)

Answer (score 2):

Since all of those are server-side elements  (you have them as `runat="server"`) the easiest way to clear the values is simply to do:

```
elementID.Value="";
```

On all of them after postback. If you are saying that the values are not being cleared after doing the above, it's probably because you are not checking `if(!IsPostback)` before executing the function that populates the values in the first place.

Your client side code should also work but it's probably failing because your last parameter to the RegisterStartupScript is `true`, which indicates that the `<script>` tags ought to be added. This may cause a problem because your function is already enclosed in `<script>` tags so the last `true` parameter is not needed in this case.